# JSON parsed file returning string instead of Array in node/express

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, express

I am having trouble when trying to parse an empty (stringified) Array from a JSON file, instead of returning an empty array, I am getting a string.

My JSON file initial set up is:

```
"[]"
```

I am assigning the parsed data to a variable using File System

```
let parsedObjs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/data/employees.json'));
```

When I try this in a browser console, I get an empty array as I would expect:

```
JSON.parse("[]")
> []
```

However, in Node/Express I am getting a string returned:

```
console.log(type of:', typeof parsedObjs);
> type of: string
```

Bizarrely, if I set up initial file as an unstringified Array it returns an Array:

```
> []
```

But of course, this produces an 'Unexpected end of JSON' error.

I'm very new to this, please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

**EXTRA INFO**

Function in it's entirety:

```
function populateSelectors(selector) {
  let foundOptions = [];
  let parsedObjs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/employees.json'));

  parsedObjs.forEach(obj => {
      let key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
      let optionName = obj[key][selector];
      if (foundOptions.indexOf(optionName) === -1 ) {
          foundOptions.push(optionName);
      }
  });
  return foundOptions;
}
```

ERROR in Full (I've obviously changed the full path to ):

```html
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
application.js:630
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.populateSelectors (<FULL PATH>\Rota Application 2\staff.js:14:27)
    at <FULL PATH>\Rota Application 2\app.js:45:28
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (<FULL PATH>\Rota Application 2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (<FULL PATH>\Rota Application 2\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (<FULL PATH>\Rota Application 2\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (<FULL PATH>\Rota Application 2\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at <FULL PATH>\Rota Application 2\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
```

**SOLVED!**

The problem was I had a writeFile method elsewhere, they were both trying to access the file at the same time. I changed it to writeFileSync and problem solved!

Answer (score 4):

It's normal, the file is not in the right format, you must remove the quotation marks.

[]

JSON.parse("[]") works with quotation marks because you must pass a string to the parse function.

Comment: I see, thank you. How can I do this while avoiding the resulting JSON error ("Unexpected end of JSON input")?

Answer (score 2):

By Best guess as to what is happening:

If you store your empty array as `"[]"` in your file, when you read it in node JS, the string seen by the parse will look like this: `"\"[]\""`.

So as far as the parser is concerned, it is parsing a string and returns the string. (Like doing `JSON.parse('\"[]\"');`)

Any file read by `readFile` WILL BE A STRING. So it is sufficient to keep your empty array as `[]` without the quotes in your JSON file

Comment: I see, thank you. How can I do this while avoiding the resulting JSON error ("Unexpected end of JSON input")?

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be happening. I tried a quick PoC with a file with just `[]` in it. And I tried parsing it like this: `var x = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./t.json'))` and it worked as expected. Can you share your call and the complete error? I see some of it in the question but it's confusing because there are syntax errors like : `console.log(type of:', typeof parsedObjs);`

Comment: Another option you can try is the [`node-fs-extra`](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) package which provides a wrapper around the native `fs` module to include convenience methods like `readJsonSync`

Comment: My post was a little confusingly written, the "console.log(type of:', typeof parsedObjs);" wasn't an error, I was just demonstrating the line of code and the result underneath. I've added the additional info you've requested. I will try node-fs-extra in the mean time.

Comment: I've just tried fs-extra, and weirdly I'm getting the same error.

Comment: That is very strange. The only reason I can think of is the JSON file has a problem. Perhaps the path of the file is not okay? Can you add a console.log to see what the result of `readFileSync` is and share that? I faced a similar issue when there were some hidden characters for file/line termination in my JSON when I copied it over from my Windows PC to my Mac. Can you also try creating a new json file with just `[]` in it and seeing if it works?

Comment: I think I figured it out! I had a writeFile method that wasn't synchronous.  I guess it was accessing the file while also trying to read it. Something that's apparently caught quite a few people out. 
https://github.com/jprichardson/node-jsonfile/issues/79
https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/622

Thank you for helping me eliminate other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, then I realize the mistake. I stringify a string `"[]"` instead an object `[]`

[image]

[image]